# why doesn't "which ruby" output anything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debian

I'm using Debian 6. I uninstalled ruby1.8, and then I installed ruby1.9.1.

If I type "which ruby" at the command line, it doesn't output anything. It seems like it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Also, you might try `locate ruby` to see where it is, and `echo $PATH` to see what directories are searched for executables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby installs on Debian/Ubuntu don't seem to generate the symbolic /usr/bin/ruby link to the specific install you have (theoretically, so that you can have multiple versions installed point to whatever version you want to use as your default).

so...

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 /usr/bin/ruby
```

should get you rolling.  If `which ruby1.9.1` is returning a different path to 1.9.1, then use that instead.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1544088 It just seems that this part of the link is wrong, change ruby-dev1.9.1 to ruby1.9.1-dev